# Access Violation comes if application opening from cmd with administrative privilege on windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, cmd

I am using simple code Test.c-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("hello\n");
while(1);
}
```

I am compiling this code by cl.exe compiler and generating Test.exe. Now I there is two way to open Test.exe. First is simple double click and open it. In this condition if I am checking Windbg(File->attach to process), It shows

```
Session: 1 User: .......
```

Now if I open Test.exe from cmd with administrative privilege and checking Windbg again, It shows

```
Error 0xD0000022
```

I thing this is a error of access violation and this is happening because cmd(admin) process does not allowing some access rights to its child Test.exe and I don't know what are those access rights.

Is there any api to allow access and remove this error. I tried these apis but nothing happening-

```
GetCurrentProcess(); //to get the pseudo handle of current process 
SetSecurityInfo(ph,SE_SERVICE,BACKUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I also opened safari browser in both ways, same result is coming like Test.exe. Please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thing this is a error of access violation and this is happening
>   because cmd(admin) process does not allowing some access rights to its
>   child Test.exe

Not quite. Run *WinDBG* with admin rights too, then the problem will go away.